# Updating last 4 <td> in each <tr> beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a html file containing (its created from PrettyTable python lib):

```
<table>
<tr>
<td> 1 </td>
<td> 1 </td>
<td> 1 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> 2 </td>
<td> 2 </td>
<td> 2 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> 3 </td>
<td> 3 </td>
<td> 3 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I would like to update  the last 2 cells of each row to have a different background using Beautifulsoup. so, for example update it to:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td> 1 </td>
<td style="background-color:blue;text-align:center;"> 1 </td>
<td style="background-color:blue;text-align:center;"> 1 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> 2 </td>
<td style="background-color:blue;text-align:center;"> 2 </td>
<td style="background-color:blue;text-align:center;"> 2 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> 3 </td>
<td style="background-color:blue;text-align:center;"> 3 </td>
<td style="background-color:red;text-align:center;"> 3 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

any assistance would be gratefully received

matt

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the exact expected output?

Comment: Please post the code that is giving you trouble.

Comment: What specifically is the issue? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something along these lines:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
options = """[your html above]"""
for i in range(2,4):
    targets = soup.select(f'tr td:nth-child({i})')
    for target in targets:            
        target['style']="background-color:blue;text-align:center;"
soup
```

Output should be your expected html in the question.